# Why is my code only putting the last value in the iteration into my data frame team_perf?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, screen-scraping

The code doesn't include any other values other than what is there for the LAL in team_perf. It should include data for every team, not just the lakers. That is why i am iterating through every team abbreviation:

```
team_abbreviations = ['NOP','BRK','OKC','NYK','DET','ATL','POR','CHI','MIL','TOR','IND',
 'UTA','DEN','SAC','GSW','MIN','ORL','BOS','CHO',
 'MEM','MIA','WAS','HOU','SAS','LAC','PHI','CLE','PHO','DAL','LAL']





for i in team_abbreviations:
   url = r'https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/{0}/2022/gamelog-advanced/'.format(i)

   team_perf = pd.read_html(url)[0]
```

Comment: Every iteration you override the value of `team_perf`. Try using [pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) in order to collect all the data.

Comment: Do you know what that would look like? I have tried several variations of team_perf2 = pd.concat([team_perf], ignore_index=False)

Answer (score 0):

You need to append your result at each run:

```
import pandas as pd
team_abbreviations = ['NOP','BRK','OKC','NYK']




DF = []
for i in team_abbreviations:
    url = r'https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/{0}/2022/gamelog-advanced/'.format(i)
    team_perf = pd.read_html(url)[0]
    DF.append(team_perf)
    
DF = pd.concat(DF)
```

which gives:

```
Unnamed: 0_level_0 Unnamed: 1_level_0 Unnamed: 2_level_0  \
                   Rk                  G               Date   
0                   1                  1         2021-10-20   
1                   2                  2         2021-10-22   
2                   3                  3         2021-10-23   
3                   4                  4         2021-10-25   
4                   5                  5         2021-10-27   
..                ...                ...                ...   
48                 45                 45         2022-01-18   
49                 46                 46         2022-01-20   
50                 47                 47         2022-01-23   
51                 48                 48         2022-01-24   
52                 49                 49         2022-01-26   

   Unnamed: 3_level_0 Unnamed: 4_level_0 Unnamed: 5_level_0  \
   Unnamed: 3_level_1                Opp                W/L   
0                 NaN                PHI                  L   
1                   @                CHI                  L   
2                   @                MIN                  L   
3                   @                MIN                  W   
4                 NaN                ATL                  L   
..                ...                ...                ...   
48                NaN                MIN                  L   
49                NaN                NOP                  L   
50                NaN                LAC                  W   
51                  @                CLE                  L   
52                  @                MIA                  L   

   Unnamed: 6_level_0 Unnamed: 7_level_0 Advanced         ...  \
                   Tm                Opp     ORtg   DRtg  ...   
0                  97                117     98.6  119.0  ...   
1                 112                128    111.3  127.2  ...   
2                  89                 96     86.2   93.0  ...   
3                 107                 98    109.5  100.3  ...   
4                  99                102    107.0  110.2  ...   
..                ...                ...      ...    ...  ...   
48                110                112    111.4  113.4  ...   
49                 91                102     98.8  110.7  ...   
50                110                102    115.9  107.5  ...   
51                 93                 95     99.5  101.6  ...   
52                 96                110    105.4  120.8  ...   

   Unnamed: 18_level_0 Offensive Four Factors                     \
   Unnamed: 18_level_1                   eFG%  TOV%  ORB% FT/FGA   
0                  NaN                   .489  11.8  19.6   .065   
1                  NaN                   .569  14.5  20.5   .149   
2                  NaN                   .399  22.0  38.2   .202   
3                  NaN                   .506  14.9  33.3   .218   
4                  NaN                   .489   8.5  20.9   .086   
..                 ...                    ...   ...   ...    ...   
48                 NaN                   .538  16.0  26.8   .300   
49                 NaN                   .435  13.9  30.4   .312   
50                 NaN                   .516  10.8  30.6   .176   
51                 NaN                   .488  10.6  22.0   .131   
52                 NaN                   .512  15.8  32.6   .133   

   Unnamed: 23_level_0 Defensive Four Factors                     
   Unnamed: 23_level_1                   eFG%  TOV%  DRB% FT/FGA  
0                  NaN                   .594  11.3  85.0   .188  
1                  NaN                   .607  12.3  75.0   .225  
2                  NaN                   .469  15.9  75.5   .063  
3                  NaN                   .428   9.7  80.4   .233  
4                  NaN                   .458   9.6  62.5   .146  
..                 ...                    ...   ...   ...    ...  
48                 NaN                   .512  10.9  80.5   .358  
49                 NaN                   .572  12.3  91.9   .197  
50                 NaN                   .519  11.5  86.0   .253  
51                 NaN                   .512  17.5  73.9   .148  
52                 NaN                   .608  16.9  80.6   .270  

[207 rows x 28 columns]
​
```